# LS_COLORS how persist after sudo su

Tags: bash, sudo, ls, colors

I have a username created on my machine and the username is added to sudoers file to have root access.

My `.bashrc` file also contains a script which is saying to change the colors for the PS1 and the colors for ls commands

```
export PS1="\[\e[1;32m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[0m\] "
export LS_COLORS="di=1:fi=0:ln=31:pi=5:so=5:bd=5:cd=5:or=31:mi=0:ex=35:*.rpm=90"
```

by the end of the script I also have the command `sudo su` to make me directly root when I'm log in.

The problem is the PS1 persist and the colors change after `sudo su` but the ls commands are still the default ones. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo -l` as your regular user to see the options currently in effect.

- Does the output include `env_reset`? If so, only a short list of safe/essential environment variables will be preserved when going through `sudo`. You can use `env_check` and/or `env_keep` keywords in the `sudoers` file to specify environment variables that will be allowed through `sudo`.
- Does the output include `always_set_home`? If so, then the `$HOME` environment variable will point to the home directory of the target user, i.e. `/root` in your case. As a result, the resulting shell will run `/root/.bashrc` rather than your personal one, and likewise all programs will look for their user-specific configuration files under `/root/` directory rather than your personal home directory.

If `sudo -s` uses root's `.bashrc` rather than your personal one, then `always_set_home` is most likely in effect (or you have a weird distribution with draconian PAM modules or something). In that case, use `visudo` to edit your sudoers file, and add one of the following lines (the exclamation mark before the name of option means "not"):

- `Defaults !always_set_home` unsets the option for all users.
- `Defaults>root !always_set_home` unsets it for all transitions to the root user, whoever the original user is.
- `Defaults:johndoe !always_set_home` unsets it for transitions where `johndoe` is the original user only.

Order matters: the last setting wins, so if there are any existing `Defaults` lines in your `sudoers` file, you should add your customizations after them.

---

And if you chain `su` after `sudo`, it will apply its own rules, which are usually not configurable. The behavior (and even availability) of `su -p` or `su -m` varies between different Linux distributions and versions.

`sudo su` means switching from your regular user to root, and then again from root to root, maximizing the chances for disruption of carefully-adjusted personal environment settings for little gain. With `sudo -s` you can achieve the same thing, either directly or with some tweaking of `Defaults` options in the `sudoers` file, depending on your preferences and choice of Linux distribution.

`sudo su -`, on the other hand, is the *obsolete* way to say "I explicitly want the environment to be just as if the target user (i.e. root) logged in directly; I want no trace of my personal environment to remain in the resulting session." If you have a version of `sudo` that was released on this millennium, you can use `sudo -i` instead to achieve that.

In the 2010s, the only reasons to use `sudo su` or `sudo su -` are probably muscle memory, following outdated advice, or dealing with truly old systems. You should probably unlearn these two commands.

Comment: Yes is running the root profile, this is what I was thinking, so there is any way to change or to make it to ignore the root profile ?

Comment: I edited my answer to cover it.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo su -p` will preserve the calling user's environment, with a few exceptions.  The exceptions can be found in the [`su` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html), but the relevant part is:

```
   -m, -p, --preserve-environment
          Preserve the entire environment, i.e. it does not set HOME,
          SHELL, USER nor LOGNAME.  This option is ignored if the option
          --login is specified.
```